# Are there any layout comparison / vssetting sharing places?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, layout

Well, I reinstalled Visual Studio 2008 and did not have a backup of my vssetting file. I did not think it was that important as I had barely customised it, however it just doesn't feel right!

The general windows feel correct but When I switch between views (source code, Windows forms, web editor), all the toolbars get muddled up.

In the past few years, I have seen so many "post your desktop" type items and I could swear there there would be some "post your IDE", but after looking on Google and several other programming sites, I just can't find one!

I don't want this turning in to a post your IDE unless others want to, but can anyone point me to a site where they have done this, or even better - are there any vssetting sharing places where you can download ones made by others?

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman has a great medley post of [Visual Studio settings themes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx).

Kindness,

Dan

PS: My favourite is Rob Conery's Vibrant ink ;)

Comment: +1, thanks, good link - but I am looking more for general setting files and not just text layouts.

Answer (score 2):

http://studiostyles.info/ is a newer site - that let's people build online and share their VSSettings themes. It is still mostly based on colors, but I can image that this could one day turn into more.